# How to access third level value in multidimensional mixed associative and numeric array

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am working with the array below and wish to ask how should I access/reference values in 'match_id' and 'match_comp_ID'?

I need to reference it in two ways: Question 1: firstly in a foreach statement. This has been answered below:

```
foreach $jason_a['matches'] as $match {
echo $match['match_id']
echo $match['match_comp_id']
}
```

Question 2: I want to sort the output from the above by those same two keys by using a sort function which I will call via usort:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
  {
    // sort by match_id
        $retval = strnatcmp(substr($b->match_id,0,10), substr($a->match_id,0,10));
    // if identical, sort by match_comp_id
  if(!$retval)     $retval = strnatcmp($a->match_comp_id, $b->match_comp_id);
    return $retval;

  }

usort($json_a, "cmp");
```

Using `match_id` or `$json['match_id]` format in the sort function don't work. I am at a loss to know what to search for.

Array is:

```
array(4) { 

 ["APIRequestsRemaining"]=> int(920) 
 ["matches"]=> array(3) { 

                [0]=> array(3) { 
                        ["match_id"]=> string(7) "1999477" 
                        ["match_static_id"]=> string(7) "1755895" 
                        ["match_comp_id"]=> string(4) "1204" } 

                [1]=> array(3) { 
                        ["match_id"]=> string(7) "1999478" 
                        ["match_static_id"]=> string(7) "1755891" 
                        ["match_comp_id"]=> string(4) "1204" } 

                [2]=> array(3) { 
                        ["match_id"]=> string(7) "1999479" 
                        ["match_static_id"]=> string(7) "1755894" 
                        ["match_comp_id"]=> string(4) "1204" } 
         } 
 ["Action"]=> string(5) "today" 
 ["Params"]=> array(4) { 
                ["Action"]=> string(5) "today" 
                ["APIKey"]=> string(31) "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" 
                ["OutputType"]=> string(4) "JSON" 
                ["comp_id"]=> string(4) "1204" 
         }
```

The php manual states: 
    `Arrays and objects can not be used as keys. Doing so will result in a warning: Illegal offset type`. I think this is my problem. But if arrays cannot be used as keys, then how do I access this key-value?

Comment: .. `foreach (['matches'] as $x){ echo $x['match_id']` ..

Comment: Thanks, answers Question 1.

Comment: please only post one question at a time

Comment: Sorry, didn't know whether it was best to continue or start a new one. Edited as I thought they were related.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($json_a['matches'] as $match) {
    // do something with $match['match_id'] and $match['match_comp_id']
}
```

For part 2 of your question, you really want to pass the 'matches' sub-array to your sort function:

```
$matches = $json_a['matches'];
usort($matches, 'cmp');
// now the $matches array should be sorted according to rules in function cmp()
```

Comment: Thanks, answers my Question 1 perfectly.

Comment: Using $matches = $json_a['matches'];
usort($matches, 'cmp'); foreach ($jason_a['matches'] as $match) {echo $match['match_id'];} I get error: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Sorry - posted wrong data: $retval = strnatcmp(substr($b->match_id,0,10), substr($a->match_id,0,10)); and also  if(!$retval)   $retval = strnatcmp($a->match_comp_id, $b->match_comp_id);

Comment: You are using object property access syntax with `->`, but each match that ends up populating `$a` and `$b` is an array. Use array notation instead: `$a['match_id']`

Comment: Have amended. Now no error but not sorting. Will double check everything and report back.

Comment: I would recommend posting a new question now that this has moved on to  Part 3. When posting include the sorting function code and be sure to post your current output after sorting, and explain what the desired output should look like.